# Confusion with change of variables in multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So in maths class recently we have started doing multiple integrals, and im pretty fine with everything until we started doing change of variables. I understand the logic behind it - finding a map such that we make a simpler shape to integrate, and using the jacobian as a kind of key to give where the transformation takes place. but I dont understand how you find the new variables - our professor told us to rewrite the constraints to find the 'obivous' change of variable, but this never works out for me. example

Compute the integral $\iint_S xy \,dx\,dy$ where

S = {(x, y) | |x + 2y| ≤ 3, |x − y| ≤ 3},

by finding a suitable change of variables.

so i tried rearranging the lines to find some kind of pattern but honestly i am so lost! does anyone have any tips as to how to start these kinds of problems?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have $-3 \leqslant x+2y \leqslant 3$ and $-3 \leqslant x-y \leqslant 3$ , so you can put $u=x+2y$ and $v=x-y$ so in uv plane you will get a rectangle having limits -3 to 3 for both variables.